# When is the exponential law in topology discontinuous?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

By $Y^X$ I mean the space of continuous functions $X \to Y$ with the compact-open topology (by compact I don't require Hausdorff. Consider the exponential law $Z^{X \times Y} \to (Z^Y)^X$ where the map is well-defined a a set map (this is not hard to see). However I don't think it's always continuous, but I don't have any examples of it being discontinuous. I know that $X$ Hausdorff implies continuous. So any counterexample must have $X$ non-hausdorff.

Comment: Hausdorff is not enough, you need locally compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @freakish Hausdorff is enough. Local compactness is needed to show that the exponential map $\Lambda : Z^{X \times Y} \to (Z^Y)^X$ is a bijection.

Comment: @PaulFrost Also Hausdorff is not needed. Engelking’s proof does not use Hausdorffness, as far as I could see. The compact-open topology on $X$ always makes the exponential map continuous.

Comment: So in engelking there's a restriction to compact Hausdorff subspaces. If you read my answer below you'll notice the problem goes away if the compact sets are Hausdorff

Comment: @davik Where does Engelking use (in his proof of 3.4.1 or lemma 3.1.15) that his compact subset is Hausdorff? I don't see it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma In fact, if $f : X \times Y \to Z$ is continuous, then $\Lambda(f) : X \to Z^Y$ is continuous wiithout any assumptions on $X, Y, Z$. Engelking shows in Theorem 3.4.7 that $\Lambda : X^{X \times Y} \to (Z^Y)^X$ is continuous. The crucial ingredient is Lemma 3.4.6 whose proof uses the normality of compact spaces. Here Hausdorff is required.

Comment: @PaulFrost I see, I should have looked a bit further. Thx.

Comment: Your questions show that you are interested in the exponential law. This depends on the construction of a good **exponential topology** on $Z^Y$. The compact-open topology is the usual choice, and it nicely works for $Y$ locally compact. But now have a look at Escardó, Martín, Jimmie Lawson, and Alex Simpson. "Comparing Cartesian closed categories of (core) compactly generated spaces." Topology and its Applications 143.1-3 (2004): 105-145 http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/Sources/comparing.pdf In my opinion this is the most satisfactory approach.

Comment: Instead of local compactness the concept of **core compactness** is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further thought, I believe I can characterize all counterexamples. We define two compact splitting qualities as follows, $X$ weakly compact-splits if for every $C \subseteq X$ compact, $U_1,U_2$ open in $X$ covering $C$, there are two compact subsets of $X$, $A_1 \subseteq U_1$ and $A_2 \subseteq U_2$ such that for any two open sets $V_1,V_2$ containing $A_1,A_2$ respectively, $C \subseteq V_1 \cup V_2$. $X$ strongly compact splits if we can choose $A_1,A_2$ to cover $C$. I claim that the exponential law is always continuous iff X weakly compact splits.

Below $M(C,U)$ denotes all continuous maps sending $C$ into $U$ and $\phi$ denotes 
the exponential law map.

If $X$ doesn't weakly compact-split, let $Z$ be the Sierpinski space $\{0,1\}$ with open sets $\{\{\},\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$ and $Y$ be the space $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology. Now, consider the map $f : X \times Y \to Z$ mapping
$U_1 \times \{0\} \cup U_2 \times \{1\}$ to $0$ with $U_1,U_2$ a cover of $C$ which doesn't split. Then, this continuous map thought of as in $(Z^Y)^X$ is inside the set $M(C,(M(\{0\},\{0\}) \cup M(\{1\},\{0\}))$ which is open, but I claim the pre-image is not open in $Z^{X \times Y}$. It's easy to see that because $Z$ only has $1$ non-trivial open set, $M(D,\{0\})$ forms a **basis** for $Z^{X \times Y}$. Now suppose
$f \in M(D,\{0\}) \subseteq \phi^{-1}\left(M(C,(M(\{0\},\{0\}) \cup M(\{1\},\{0\}))\right)$.
We would have that $D = D_1 \times \{0\} \cup D_2 \times \{1\}$ where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are compact in $X$. Now $f \in M(D,\{0\})$ means $D_1 \subseteq U_1$ and $D_2 \subseteq U_2$ and the subset inclusion $M(D,\{0\}) \subseteq \phi^{-1}\left(M(C,(M(\{0\},\{0\}) \cup M(\{1\},\{0\}))\right)$ implies any two open sets $V_1,V_2$ containing $D_1,D_2$ respectively must have $C \subseteq V_1 \cup V_2$. Contradiction.

Alternatively, suppose $X$ weakly compact-splits. Then we consider a $f: X \times Y \to Z$ continuous such that $f$ (thought of as in $(Z^Y)^X$) is in 
$M(C,\cup_{i \in I}(\cap_{j \in J_i}{M(L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}))$. 
We wish to show that the inverse image under $\phi$ is a neighborhood of $f$. Now because $f:X \to Z^Y$ is continuous and $C$ is compact, we can assume $I$ is finite. That is, replace $I$ with some finite subset such that $f$ is still in  $M(C,\cup_{i \in I}(\cap_{j \in J_i}{M(L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}))$. Now we apply the strong compact splitting property many times to find compact sets $D_i$ indexed by $I$ such that
$f(D_i) \subseteq \cap_{j \in J_i}{M(L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}$ and such that if $D_i \subseteq V_i$ for each $i$ then $C \subseteq \cup V_i$. Now we claim that in $Z^{X \times Y}$ the set $\cap_{i\in I,j\in J_i}{M(D_i \times L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}$ contains $f$ and is contained in the preimage as desired. Suppose $g : X \times Y \to Z$ is
continuous and $g(D_i \times L_{i,j}) \subseteq U_{i,j}$. Then $g(D_i) \subseteq
\cap_{j \in J_i}{M(L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}$ so because $g:X \to Z^Y$ is continuous, 
$g(C) \subseteq  \cup_{i \in I}(\cap_{j \in J_i}{M(L_{i,j},U_{i,j})}$ as desired.

Now, for the example we note that $\alpha(\mathbb{Q})$ doesn't weakly compact split, so it must produce a counterexample.

New question is: does weakly compact split imply strongly compact split?

Edit: To further understand the situation, we should ask when the reverse map $(Z^Y)^X \to Z^{X \times Y}$ is continuous. Now this map may not always be defined, so we can instead ask the question with the image space being all functions from $X \times Y \to Z$ not necessarily continuous, and here I believe the answer is yes if for every compact set of $X \times Y$ and an open neighborhood there is a covering of the compact set by products of compact sets in $X$ and $Y$ which is contained in the neighborhood. This is satisfied if either $X$ or $Y$ is locally compact, meaning that we get an homeomorphism onto image of the map in the original question if $X$ is locally compact, but not necessarily a surjective map.

Comment: Why are you interested in "strongly compact splitting"?

Comment: It is easy to see that each  locally compact $X$ strongly compact splits.

Comment: Is your definition of locally compact strongly locally compact, if so I'd like to see a proof. Also I'm interested in strong compact splitting because it seems more natural of a definition to me, but to be honest I haven't given too much thought on a weak compact splittable space that's not strongly splittable

Comment: In my understanding $X$ is locally compact if for  each $x \in X$ and each open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exist an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and a compact $C  \subset X$ such that $V \subset C  \subset U$.

Comment: Oh yes I see it is easy, I didn't think of it before, you just take a compact neighborhood at each point and apply the finite subcover property.

Comment: So you get an exponential homeomorphism $\Lambda : Z^{X \times Y} \to (Z^Y)^X$  for **any** $X,Z$ and **any** locally compact $Y$.

Comment: I think you need Y and X both locally compact?

Comment: Yes, you are right! You get an exponential homeomorphism for any $Z$, any weakly compact-splittng $X$ and any locally compact $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a paper by P. Booth and J. Tillotson, Pacific  J. Math. 
Vol.  88.  No. 1,  198 (downloadable) which discusses  exponential laws $X ^{Z \times Y} \cong (X^Y)^Z$ for various function space topologies,  and topologies on $X \times Y$.

Comment: Thanks, I briefly skimmed through the paper but it seems difficult to apply its results here since the spaces a priori have no reason to be regular which is used in that paper so often. However, thanks for the reference