# Definition of continuous representation of topological group

Tags: general-topology, continuity, representation-theory, topological-groups, topological-vector-spaces

I have a question about the definition of continuous representation of topological group.

Let $G$ be a group and $\rho : G \rightarrow {\rm Aut}_k(V)$ be a representation of  $G$ , where $k$ is a field
and $V$ is a topological space and finite dimensional vector space.

${\rm Map}(V,V)$ is the topological space by compact-open topology.
We consider ${\rm Aut}_k (V)$ as a topological subspace of ${\rm Map}(V,V)$.
$\rho$ is a continuous map under this setting.

> **[My question]**
>   Two conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ is equivalent $??$
>   $(1)$ $\rho$ is a continuous map of topological spaces.
>   $(2)$ For any element $g \in G$ , $\rho (g)$ is a continuous map.

I think $(2)$ is the definition of continuous representation.
$(1)$ may be the definition. Please give me opinions $!!$

Comment: (2) is not good enough : it doesn't take the topology of $G$ into account; moreover for many purposes $V$ will be normed and finite dimensional so all linear maps are continuous and so (2) wouldn't make sense.

Comment: "Let $G$ be a group": should be "Let $G$ be a topological group"?

Comment: This is covered by your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3162758.