# Discontinuous uncurrying map

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Suppose $f: X\to \mathcal{C}(Y,Z)$ is a continuous map of topological spaces. The *uncurrying* map is $\beta_f: X\times Y\to Z$, $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)(y)$. I know that this $\beta_f$ map is always continuous if $Y$ is locally compact and Hausdorff. So this led me to try to find an example of such an $f$ which leads to a discontinuous $\beta_f$. My thought was to use $\mathbb{Q}=Y$ (with subspace topology) since this space is not locally compact. But I could not find an appropriate $f$ that makes $\beta_f$ not continuous.

Any thoughts?

Edit: Note $\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)$ has the compact open topology. Ie, the topology generated by $o(K,U)$ where $K\subset Y$ is compact and $U\subset Z$ is open.

Comment: I think you'd be better off trying not Hausdorff. I'm thinking the indiscrete topology.

Comment: What type of function are you thinking?

Comment: The only continuous functions in the indiscrete topology are constant. It's just a guess, I don't know if it would work out.

Comment: What topology are you putting on $\mathcal{C}(Y,Z)$?  The compact-open topology?

Comment: Yes the compact open. Sorry I should edit that

Comment: "Uncurry" seems to be a very unusual expression.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a duplicate of [$\operatorname{Hom}(X \times Z, Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(X, \operatorname{Map}(Z, Y))$ is not true in $\textbf{Top}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3450917)

Let $X= C(Y,Z)$ and $f = id$. Then $\beta_f$ is the evaluation map $\Omega : C(Y,Z) \times Y \to Z,(\phi,y) \mapsto \phi(y)$.

Now see [$\operatorname{Hom}(X \times Z, Y) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(X, \operatorname{Map}(Z, Y))$ is not true in $\textbf{Top}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3450917) for examples where $\Omega$ is not continuous. In fact, $Y = \mathbb Q$ and $Z = [0,1]$ will do.